# JQuery test with Jasmine fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am new to JQuery and have to test this function with Jasmine:

```
showUserDeleted: function (event) {
    $('#loginError').html((new ErrorView({code: "login"})).render().$el);
}
```

I devided this function into two:

```
showFailedLogin: function (event) {
    var value = (new ErrorView({code: "login"})).render().$el;
    showFailedLoginHelper(event, value);
},

showFailedLoginHelper: function (event, value){
    $('#loginError').html(value);
},
```

Now I want to test the helper function.

```
//...
var view;
var $;

beforeAll(function(done){
    require(['../../../public/js/app/views/LoginView', 'jquery'],
        function(LoginView, Jquery) {
            view = new LoginView();
            $ = view.getJQuery();
            done();
        }
    );
});

describe("showFailedLogin", function(){
    it ("should add something to loginError", function(){
        var input = "asdf";
        view.showFailedLoginHelper(undefined, input);
        expect( $('#loginError').html()).toBe(input);
    });
});
//...
```

When I run this it says:

```
Expected undefined to be 'asdf'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: console.log() your selector.length to see if it is 1.  if not, your element is not being generated on the page.

Comment: And it strikes me as as strange that you are providing an event to the login helper and not using it, and in your testing your providing it as 'undefined'.  Is this code still in progress?  Why do you need this parameter?

Comment: selector.length is 0. how can i fix that? i still don't really understand how requirejs works... shouldn't this be generated when I create an instance of `LoginView`?

Comment: i didn't write the code for this project and it is still in progress. that's why i didn't remove the parameter.

Comment: I do not have experience with require js outside of some fiddling (not the site).  My personal jasmine experience is based on myself generating the needed tags on the page, within a container, for the logic to work against.  Not pulling in an actual html view or page.  Others may can advise.